# Error while loading shared libraries: libdl.so.2 (and others), no such file. Libraries exist

Tags: centos, software-installation, java, libraries

Attempting to install a Java application from a .bin file.  When opening the installer from command line, I see these errors:

```
[boxen]# ./ZendStudio-5_2_0.bin 
Preparing to install...
Extracting the JRE from the installer archive...
Unpacking the JRE...
Extracting the installation resources from the installer archive...
Configuring the installer for this system's environment...
awk: error while loading shared libraries: libdl.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
dirname: error while loading shared libraries: libc.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
/bin/ls: error while loading shared libraries: libc.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
basename: error while loading shared libraries: libc.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
dirname: error while loading shared libraries: libc.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
basename: error while loading shared libraries: libc.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
hostname: error while loading shared libraries: libnsl.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Launching installer...

grep: error while loading shared libraries: libc.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
/tmp/install.dir.7515/Linux/resource/jre/bin/java: error while loading shared libraries: libpthread.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

...

The catch is that every one of these objects exist on the system.

```
# locate libdl.so.2
/usr/lib/libdl.so.2
/usr/lib64/libdl.so.2

# locate libc.so.6
/usr/lib/libc.so.6
/usr/lib/i686/nosegneg/libc.so.6
/usr/lib64/libc.so.6

# locate libnsl.so.1
/usr/lib/libnsl.so.1
/usr/lib64/libnsl.so.1
```

If I issue this,

```
echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

I get nothing.

So, I add include directories to the path:

```
[boxen]# LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib:/usr/lib64/:/usr/local/lib/:/usr/local/lib64/
[boxen]# echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
/usr/lib:/usr/lib64/:/usr/local/lib/:/usr/local/lib64/
```

And re-run the installer...

```
[boxen]# ./ZendStudio-5_2_0.bin 
Preparing to install...
Extracting the JRE from the installer archive...
Unpacking the JRE...
Extracting the installation resources from the installer archive...
Configuring the installer for this system's environment...
awk: error while loading shared libraries: libdl.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
dirname: error while loading shared libraries: libc.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
/bin/ls: error while loading shared libraries: libc.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
basename: error while loading shared libraries: libc.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
dirname: error while loading shared libraries: libc.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
basename: error while loading shared libraries: libc.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
hostname: error while loading shared libraries: libnsl.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Launching installer...

grep: error while loading shared libraries: libc.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
/tmp/install.dir.8055/Linux/resource/jre/bin/java: error while loading shared libraries: libpthread.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

...

Exact same batch of errors.

Installed Java version:

```
java version "1.7.0_65"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (rhel-2.5.1.2.el7_0-x86_64 u65-b17)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.65-b04, mixed mode)
```

Installed glib:

```
# rpm -qa | grep glibc
glibc-2.17-55.el7.i686
glibc-2.17-55.el7.x86_64
glibc-headers-2.17-55.el7.x86_64
glibc-common-2.17-55.el7.x86_64
glibc-devel-2.17-55.el7.x86_64
```

What could be causing the installer to not see files that are plainly there and in the environment variable?

Comment: Did you export LD_LIBRARY_PATH? If you just say LD_LIBRARY_PATH=(value), then it's visible only to the shell itself, and not to programs.

Comment: Yes, but this wasn't the issue.  Just posted the answer: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/152862/20107

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I feel lucky in stumbling across this solution, but wanted to post it up in case anyone else runs across this issue in installing legacy software.

```
Assuming the install anywhere script is called Install.bin

# cp Install.bin Install.bak
# cat Install.bak | sed "s/export LD_ASSUME_KERNEL/#xport LD_ASSUME_KERNEL/" > Install.bin
# rm Install.bak
```

This worked nicely.

The fix was originally posted on the [Zend Knowledgebase](http://www.zend.com/support/knowledgebase.php?kbid=184&view_only=1) (now 404'ed), it is still archived on [linuxquestions.org](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/awk-could-be-jvm-error-libdl-so-2-libc-so-6-a-370056/).